# Data Table Partial Update from Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tomahawk

I'm using `Primefaces4.0`, `JSF 2.0` and `Tomahawk2.0`

I have an `p:fileUpload` which actually read data call some procedures and show results after in `t:dataTable` using `update`

I am facing a problem, If file is too large it take couple of seconds to show results (30-40 sec) which is not good practice.

I want to Populate `t:dataTable` in each of the iteration of for loop which is reading values, call procedure and show result.

Comment: is there is any way to update UI client side using `UIComponent`

Comment: Can you post bit of your sample code and explain the problem clearly

Comment: Well what you're planning on doing is no better. Instead of performing all the necessary processing server-side in one move and likewise updating the table in one move, you're planning to send traffic to the browser for every row you process? How's that more effective? If anything, it's going to double the processing time for the entire thing. Just show the users a loading graphic with `<p:blockui/>` or something. Yikes

Comment: @kolossus nice choice but when running application in production i takes too much time as process is depended on other and mean while UI is block and populate 100's of record at once. My aim is to set a progress bar along with the partial update table, As it is good for user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update any component from ManagedBean, you can use Primefaces's `update()` method on [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) .

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() .update("component_ID")
```

But I doubt that this will solve you problem.
Because RequestContext's methods will take affect when Response is returned from ManagedBean.
And that won't happen after every iteration of loop, it happens when Action method is completed.

A preferred and better way to handle huge data population in DataTable is to use the [LazyModel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml).